# How to compute expectation for the product of squared jointly normal random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, bivariate-distributions

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be jointly normal random variables with $\mathbb E[X_1] = \mathbb E[X_2] = 0$ and $\operatorname{var}(X_1) = \sigma_1^2$, $\operatorname{var}(X_2) = \sigma_2^2$. The correlation between them is $\rho$.
>
> Find $\mathbb E\left[\left(X_1^2\right)\left(X_2^2\right)\right]$.

I know that $\rho = \frac {\mathbb E[XY]} {\sigma_1 \sigma_2}$, but I'm not sure how this equation changes when $X$ and $Y$ are squared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $X_1^{2}$ and $X_2^{2}$ are independent.

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then the correlation between them is $0$

Comment: I had a mistake in the problem statement. X1 and X2 are not independent, but jointly normal. Their correlation is _p_.

Answer (score 1):

When the $X_1$and $X_2$ are jointly normal the covariance between these two would be $2{\rho}^2$

The proog is here: [covariance of two squared (not zero mean) random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889402/covariance-of-two-squared-not-zero-mean-random-variables)

If you don't like the proof here you an do something like this

[The covariance of two squared normal variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894593/the-covariance-of-two-squared-normal-variables)

Then it becomes easy

$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left [ {X_{1}}^{2}{X_{2}}^{2} \right ] = Cov \left( {X_1}^2 ,{X_2}^2 \right) + \mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left [ {X_{1}}^{2} \right ]\mathop{\mathbb{E}}\left [{X_{2}}^{2} \right ] = 2{\rho}^2 +{\sigma_{1}}^{2}  {\sigma_{2}}^{2} $$

Hope it helps you.